# mysql_fetch_array pulling fewer results than it should

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$mostRecent = mysql_query("SELECT couponID FROM users_coupons WHERE userID = '$userID' ORDER BY id LIMIT 3");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mostRecent))
    {
        $mostRecentArr = $row;
    }
    var_dump($mostRecentArr);
```

The same SQL query in the command line returns 3 results, but this code only returns one result, even though I put LIMIT 3. Any help?

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something simple, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mostRecent))
    {
        $mostRecentArr[] = $row['couponID'];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You reassign the value in the loop each time, then dump the last value. Put var_dump in the loop after the assignment. Like so:

```
$mostRecent = mysql_query("SELECT couponID FROM users_coupons WHERE userID = '$userID' ORDER BY id LIMIT 3");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mostRecent))
    {
        $mostRecentArr = $row;
        var_dump($mostRecentArr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what are you trying to do is:

```
$mostRecent = mysql_query("SELECT couponID FROM users_coupons WHERE userID = '$userID' ORDER BY id LIMIT 3");
$mostRecentArr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mostRecent))
{
    $mostRecentArr[] = $row;
}
var_dump($mostRecentArr);
```